# Passing boolean parameters to a .NET Method using NETLink

Tags: .netlink

According to the NETLink documentation, NETLink automatically handles type conversions from Mathematica to a .NET dll.  One of the issues I have is that the .NET method I want to use expects a Boolean parameter.  Using Mathematica's True or False does not work but using a 0 or 1 integer seems to.  The .NET method expects a Short numeric type when using a value of 0 or 1.  Does Mathematica automatically handle the integer head of a Mathematica value and convert it to a short that the method expects?